# My model has a strange line on it and the mesh seems seperated

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: appearance in object mode]

[image: appearance in edit mode with opening]

I've started learning blender, and I'm trying to make a mug, but it has a line on the object mode view. It seems to be because part of the mesh is seperated, but I don't remember doing that. Help?

Comment: You have selected on of the disconnected edge loops. Why don't you simply delete those vertices [X] and then remake the faces, by selecting four vertices and pressing F?

Comment: maybe you've pressed V, which rips the shape... as said by Rix, just select all and W > Remove Doubles.

Answer (score 1):

Select all vertices and in the search bar, (F3 or space) search "remove doubles." This will connect the vertices.